# Cannot assign this value at http interceptor

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework

I want to assign token key at this.token variable, but token variable is undefined

```
    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    let loader = this.loaderService.processingLoader();
    this.loaderService.start(loader);
    this.store.get('ast_access_token').then((result: string) => {
        if(result) {
            this.token = result;
        }
    });
    this.loaderService.stop(loader);
    return next.handle(req);
}
```

Comment: Do you want to say that your `result` is coming empty?

Comment: no, result have data  from local storage and i want to add result data to token variable. But this.token is undefined

Comment: did you try to console.log(result) ?

Comment: yes, result have data about jwt token.

Comment: please show what `result` you are getting?

Comment: what's the type of `this.token` and `result's`value?

Comment: token: string;  result: string